# How to scroll the element until a certain word appears?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, try-catch, webdriverwait

I'm scraping Google Maps and I need to know how to scroll the query column until the word appears

"You've reached the end of the list".
I am using selenium for scraping.
Code I currently use:

```
for a in range(100):
    barraRolagem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
    "//div[@role='main']//div[contains(@aria-label,'" + procurar + "')]")))
     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scroll(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", barraRolagem)
```

this code works, however the range is variable and is not certain, that is, it can scroll a lot and it can also scroll a little, for this reason I need to stop scrolling when the code finds the phrase

"You've reached the end of the list"

[image]

Link

https://www.google.com.br/maps/search/contabilidade+balneario+camboriu/@-26.9905418,-48.6289914,15z

Comment: why not use a `while` and check for the output that you want to check for

Comment: An alternative method would be to use Google's [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service) for data content scraping. This allows you to use Google's [Python client library for Google Maps API Web Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll in a loop until "You've reached the end of the list" text is visible.
When text is found visible - break the loop. Otherwise do a scroll.
Since in case element not visible exception is thrown `try-except` block is needed here.
Additional scroll is added after the element is found visible since Selenium detects that element visible while it is still not actually visible, so one more scroll should be done finally.
The following code works correctly:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1)

url = "https://www.google.com.br/maps/search/contabilidade+balneario+camboriu/@-26.9905418,-48.6289914,15z"
driver.get(url)
while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'reached the end')]")))
        barraRolagem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='main']//div[@aria-label]")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scroll(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", barraRolagem)
        break
    except:
        barraRolagem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='main']//div[@aria-label]")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scroll(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", barraRolagem)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: The code stopped working in FOR.

It scrolls until it finds the end of the list, but does not execute the FOR.

https://prnt.sc/L28MLBDmDGSq

Comment: That for is not related to what you asked here. You asked how to scroll and I gave you a solution doing that. In case you need some additional help - this is a new question.

Comment: I asked another question with the complete code and the WHILE.

Comment: OK, I'll take a look

Comment: What `for` you want to perform but not performed here? `for empresa in classe_empresas:` or `for paginas_individuais in links:`?

Comment: are two FOR .
It starts with the loop of the (1st FOR)URL that are in a dictionary, (2nd FOR) then the code enters these URLs and extracts data from each page

Comment: OK, let me know if I understood you correctly in the answer I wrote there. If I misunderstood - please correct me there